# All websites are zoomed

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

I restarted chrome to make an update of it. My last active tab was one, which I zoomed in by maybe 40%. Since chrome made the update an restored all my open tabs, I have the problem that all websites are zoomed in by 40%.
The big issue is, that chrome is stating that it the zoom is set to 100% (normal view) but is definitely showing all websites bigger than they should be.

Does anyone know I can reset that? It's annoying to zoom out on every page which I visit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mac browsers use Cmd and + or - to change view size, so by extrapolation Ctrl/- might just do it?

Comment: The problem is, that chromes displays all website with a zoom of 140% but is stating, that it is only 100%. I can change it with these shortcuts, but I have to do it for every site separately, which is annoying.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is some fighting going on with Windows' insistence on system zoom. That's gonna leave you in the fourth corner of a fight with 3 other contestants. Sorry :/

Comment: Do you have suggestion what I should look for? It is only Chrome which shows things differently. Everything else has the normal view in Windows at all and in the other browsers as well

Answer (score 0):

To restore your settings click on the 3 dots in the top right, go down to the bottom where it says "Show advanced settings", scroll down again then click on reset settings. I hope this helps